# Purging inactive carts in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I've a Commerce store with orders dating back to September and have the following in my config:

```
'purgeInactiveCarts' => true,
'purgeInactiveCartsDuration' => 'P1M',
```

The docs say that the purging should be triggered by me visiting the Inactive carts area of the Commerce order section, but it isn't. Does anyone know if:

1. The trigger is time limited, e.g. is only called once a day?
2. There are any known issues with the purging of inactive carts?
3. Anything else I could look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was not reading the docs properly and putting the config values in general.php. Instead, I needed to create a commerce.php config file and put the values in that. As soon as I did, the orders were purged.

Comment: Ahh... that would explain it, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The trigger is time limited, e.g. is only called once a day?

Nope.  That logic runs every time the order index page is loaded.

> 2. There are any known issues with the purging of inactive carts?

Nothing I'm aware of.

> 3. Anything else I could look at?

Here's the method and SQL query Commerce uses to determine if there are carts to purge.

```
private function getCartsIdsToPurge()
{
    $configInterval = craft()->config->get('purgeInactiveCartsDuration', 'commerce');
    $edge = new \DateTime();
    $interval = new \DateInterval($configInterval);
    $interval->invert = 1;
    $edge->add($interval);

    return Craft::app()->db->createCommand()->select('orders.id')
        ->from('commerce_orders orders')
        ->where('isCompleted=:isCompleted AND dateUpdated <= :edge', [':isCompleted' => 'not 1','edge' => $edge->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
        ->queryColumn();
}
```

Open up the orders table in the database and find a cart you think should be getting purged, but isn't.

Check if it has a 0/null value in the `isCompleted` column and a `dateUpdated` column that is (in your case) greater than 1 month old.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Can confirm they have isCompleted set to 0 an the dateUpdated is more than one month ago. While I've been working on this (3 days now) I can see the orders are being purged that are more than 3 months old. So the purging is working, it's just my config setting overriding the duration that isn't. Actually, what I think might be the problem is I've got the value in my general.php file and not created a commerce.php config file. It does say that on https://craftcommerce.com/docs/configuration but I missed it.

Comment: Yep. It was the values being in general.php and not commerce.php. Sorry.